# how to write a query with 2 equals on linq?

Tags: vb.net, linq, equals, operator-keyword

I'm a beginner in VB.NET and recently I tried to write a LinQ query. I would like to use `equals` twice in my query but it does not work the way I want, I get the following error message:

> Expression expected" on the &&

Code:

```
Dim Que2 = From couple2 In list_couple_C
           Where couple2.colonne1.Equals(My_list(j))
              && couple2.colonne2.Equals(couple1.colonne2)
           Select couple2
```

Is it possible to use two `equals` in the same query? And if so, can someone tell me what is wrong in my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&&` equivalent in VB.NET is `AndAlso`. 
`&` equivalent is just `And`.
See Below:

```
Dim Que2 = From couple2 In list_couple_C
           Where couple2.colonne1.Equals(My_list(j)) AndAlso 
           couple2.colonne2.Equals(couple1.colonne2)
           Select couple2
```